# Routing in Angular2 in a shared hosting

Tags: angular, symfony, routes, hosting

I have uploaded an application with angular2 and symfony3 in a shared hosting (1&1).

This is the website: http://s714578534.mialojamiento.es

It redirects to http://s714578534.mialojamiento.es/inicio, and it works good.

The problem is when I try to directly access to http://s714578534.mialojamiento.es/inicio , http://s714578534.mialojamiento.es/libros/1/Todos/Valoraci%C3%B3n , ... The website don't load.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Conectando Lectores</title>
   <base href="/">
   <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
   <meta name="keywords" content="Red Social, Literatura, Libros, Libro, Microcuento, Microcuentos, Autores, Autor, Autora, Lectura, Leer">
   <meta name="author" content="José Manuel Vázquez Crespo">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
   <app-root>Cargando...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
// Ruta de inicio de la aplicación
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'inicio', pathMatch: 'full'},
// Otras rutas
{ path: 'inicio', component: DefaultComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'login/:id', component: LoginComponent }, 
{ path: 'login/:email/:verificationKey', component: LoginComponent }, 
{ path: 'login/:id/:email/:verificationKey', component: LoginComponent }, 
{ path: 'registro', component: RegisterComponent },
{ path: 'perfil', component: PerfilComponent },
{ path: 'perfil/:username', component: PerfilComponent },
{ path: 'perfil/:username/:type', component: PerfilComponent },
{ path: 'mibiblioteca', component: LibraryComponent },
{ path: 'usuarios', component: UsuariosComponent },
{ path: 'mensajes', component: PrivateMessageComponent },
{ path: 'mensajes/:username', component: PrivateMessageComponent },
{ path: 'notificaciones', component: NotificationComponent },
{ path: 'politicaprivacidad', component: PoliticaPrivacidadComponent },
{ path: 'terminosycondiciones', component: TerminosyCondicionesComponent },
{ path: 'contacta', component: ContactaComponent },
{ path: 'noticias', component: NewsComponent },
{ path: 'noticias/:title', component: NewsComponent },
// Books
{ path: 'libros', redirectTo: '/libros/1/Todos/Valoración', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'libros/:page/:genre/:order/:title', component: LibrosComponent }, 
{ path: 'libros/:page/:genre/:order', component: LibrosComponent },
{ path: 'libros/:page/:titulo', component: LibrosComponent },
{ path: 'libros/:titulo', component: VisualizarlibroComponent } 
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = 
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change your .htacces

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It doesn't work in 1&1, but I have tried in other server and it works perfectly. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

for this

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

Comment: This is an easier solution :)

Comment: It works, but it puts '#' in the route. How can I delete it?

Comment: You remove the hash with setting the parameter useHash: false

Answer (score 0):

Symfony will catch any URL that does not match any file.

Move symfony to another subdomain:

http://[angular].mialojamiento.es

http://[symfony api].mialojamiento.es

You can work with subfolders as well:

http://[yourid].mialojamiento.es/api/app.php <--- symfony

http://[yourid].mialojamiento.es/ <--- angular

Comment: I have tried this, but I still have the same problem. I can access to http://s714578534.mialojamiento.es but I can't access to http://s714578534.mialojamiento.es/login

Comment: Can you add more details on the question about that? Both domains have the same name, so you may need multiple hostings

Comment: I think your issue is with the .htaccess try the answer of @habibun